# If $\operatorname{curl} \vec F \neq \vec 0$, what conditions determine whether the rotation is counter-clockwise or clockwise?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

If $\operatorname{curl} \vec F = \vec 0$, then a tiny paddle wheel moves with the fluid
but doesn’t rotate about its axis.
If $\operatorname{curl} \vec F \neq \vec 0$, the paddle wheel rotates about its axis.

I know the above two statements. **What conditions determine whether the rotation is counter-clockwise or clockwise?**

Can it be determined from $\operatorname{curl} \vec F $?

Comment: $\text{curl} \,\vec F$ is a vector field. It essentially points in the direction of the angular momentum of the rotating fluid particles. So, it points up when the fluid is rotating counterclockwise (viewed from above) and down when the fluid is rotating clockwise. (The terms clockwise and counterclockwise are sort of meaningless unless you specify a plane and an orientation.)